# Broken cabinet hinge?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

I noticed that one of my Mepla kitchen cabinet hinges looks like it's broken, as the swinging arm (from the door) at the lower left of the picture is no longer connected to the mounting plate (that is mounted at the cabinet).  Is it possible to reattach the two parts without having to replace the hinge?

[image]

Comment: You may check with the cabinet company. They may replace the hinge for free if you are the original purchaser. I've contacted KraftMaid three times and they've replaced for free. Just a thought.

Comment: Not likely. Looks like a pot metal casting, and a very thin body at that point. Seems to be held in place by pressure pins. Theoretically the pressure pins could be forced out and a new arm inserted, but much more trouble than the hinge is worth. @Paulster2 's comment seems the best approach.

Comment: Thanks Paulster2 and bib.  When I emailed 
CabinetParts.com, they told me that "These are a Mepla 170* hinge full overlay and a 0mm panel application base plate.

Mepla was recently acquired by Grass USA. Grass has now started deleting most Mepla products.

Your hinge and base are no longer available.

We can replace these with any 170* hinge and base. No matter what parts we go with, you will have to change all hinges and bases on each door the new are used on. You will have new screw holes on the door.

We will switch you to a Blum hinge and base."  It will be a pain to install a new hinge.